Keep class content when using Custom Pattern in ReSharper
I want to use ReSharper feature: Code Inspection → Custom Patterns to enforce using a certain base class.
This is how my pattern looks like:
(Please ignore the "UI glitch" -- I had to work around another problem)

The problem is the content of the class. I'd like that have a placeholder which accepts any class content. However, such a placeholder does not exist:

No matter what I try, the content of the class is always lost when I apply the pattern. Is there any solution?
I know I can use a Find pattern instead of Replace, but then I have no auto-fix options. That is not what I want...

Is there any solution? → unfortunately, I'm not aware of any solution for this
